# google gwt method comparable to paint in java

Tags: gwt, paint

I'm relatively new to google gwt and I'm search for a method, which is comparable to the paint-method in java. I would like to draw small graphics *on top* of other elements and pictures. I know, there exists the Canvas-class, but I didn't found any way to use it as an *overlay* painter.

I hope someone can help.

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need simple overlays, I would use pre-made images and the css z-index and position: relative attributes to put them on top of each other.

for actual painting you could use the GWT's Canvas (HTML5 canvas) or a 3rd party library, like [RaphaelGWT](http://code.google.com/p/raphaelgwt/), which uses SVG.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The css z-index works for my problem. I simply overlay different div-elements like in this example: http://www.css4you.de/example/z-index.html